# Compute CVAR in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to compute CVAR in Matlab. There is whole optimization class devoted to CVAR in Matlab, but I cannot figure out how to simply compute CVAR (either parametrically or from historic data)

Any suggestions?

Regads,

Comment: is [this](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/cvar-portfolio-optimization-71631.html) useful? If CVAR stadnds for conditional-value-at-risk for you.

Comment: Thank you, Parag! It is usefully, I finally found relevant functions.